# Changing the limits of a sum and combine them

Tags: limits, summation, double-sequence

could someone show me how to change the limits of a double summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\;\sum_{j = i+1}^n$ and combine them together to form $\sum_{i,j=1}^n$?

i think we must incorporate the use of $(i\wedge j)$ inside the function but i cant seem to figure out how to

Comment: What are you summing?

Comment: How about $$\displaystyle \sum_{1\le i < j \le n}$$

Comment: If you want to use $$\displaystyle \sum_{i,j=1}^n$$ then I would recommend an indicator function: $$\displaystyle \sum_{i,j=1}^n 1_{i<j}\cdot f(i,j)$$ where the indicator function $1_{i<j} = \begin{cases}1, & i<j \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: im trying to combine the double summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\;\sum_{j = i+1}^n e^{t_i+t_j}$ into something like $\sum_{i,j=1}^n e^{(t_i\wedge  t_j)}$ but it does not really make sense to me??

Comment: In that case: $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n e^{t_i+t_j} = \sum_{1\le i < j \le n} e^{t_i+t_j} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n 1_{i<j}e^{t_i+t_j}$$ so any of these work. The $\wedge$ is typically a logical AND, making its meaning in this context a bit unclear. If you described that $t_i\wedge t_j = \begin{cases}t_i+t_j, & i<j \\ -\infty, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, then I could see it kinda working. Otherwise, I do not understand your intended notation.